# Inheritance and the 'Curiously Recurring Template Pattern'

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

In an MVC project I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Browse<T> where T : Browse<T>

public abstract class SqlBrowse<T> : Browse<T> where T : Browse<T>

public class SqlBrowseBoys : SqlBrowse<SqlBrowseBoys>
public class SqlBrowseGirls : SqlBrowse<SqlBrowseGirls>
```

and the following view model

```
public class BrowseViewModel
{
    public [INTERFACE] People { get; set; }
}
```

but I need an interface/class in the position labelled [INTERFACE] that can take both SqlBrowseBoys and SqlBrowseGirls so I can use BrowseViewModel in multiple places.

I'd love it if someone could show me how as my brain is now tied in knots. I suspect this will require some change(s) to the classes and that's fine but I currently have no clue what that will be.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: Eric Lippert posted about the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx), which should be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's where I learned the name of the pattern and something about it after searching RE the above code, but it doesn't help with my current problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `SqlBrowse<T>` implement a non-generic `SqlBrowse` interface (or abstract class), and then write

```
public SqlBrowse People { get; set; }
```

It's hard to tell what changes that will entail to your classes because we don't have their definitions.

Comment: When I do that it insists that SqlBrowseBoys and SqlBrowseGirls also implement the new interface, then another knock-on effect that I resolved, then another... Difficult to describe all without posting lots of code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Mark That's probably because you wrote
"class SqlBrowse<T> : Browse<T> where T : Browse<T>, SqlBrowse { }"
when you should have written
"class SqlBrowse<T> : Browse<T>, SqlBrowse where T : Browse<T> { }"

Comment: yes, i did! thanks. i still have knock-on effects to deal with but not as many, phew.